# Obtaining Positive Solutions by the Method of Characteristics for a First Order Linear PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the function $u(x,y):{\mathbb{R}^2} \to {\mathbb{R}}$ and $u(x,y) \in {{C}^1}({\mathbb{R}^2})$. The function satisfies the following boundary value problem

$$c_1 u_x + c_2 u_y = f(x,y)$$
$$u|_{\partial \Omega} =0$$

Where $\Omega$ is an arbitrary simply connected domain in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the boundary $\partial \Omega $ which can be assumed to be smooth as you like although weaker conditions may be needed. $c_1,c_2$ are some real constants.

Find **a** function $f(x,y)$ such that  $u(x,y) >0$ for all $(x,y) \in \Omega$.

In the next step, it can be aksed that how we can find **all** such $f(x,y)$? or What are the common properties of **all** such $f(x,y)$?

Comment: I don't understand why you say _"find $f$"_. Isn't function $f$ supposed to be given as part of problem statement?

Comment: @Vlad I guess you could put it that way, but I want some freedom in choosing $f$.  Certainly this will not hold for all $f$.  For example, if $f\equiv 0$, then we get $u_x = Cu_y$, which along with the boundary condition makes $u\equiv 0$, so that there can be no positive solution.  Find the $f = f(\Omega)$ giving a positive solution $u$.

Comment: Start from **any function** $u>0$ on $\Omega$ such that $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and define $f$ by $$f(x,y)=c_1u_x(x,y)+c_2u_y(x,y),$$ *et voilà!* Or am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose it should be extended, as edited to "In the next step, it can be aksed that how we can find all such f(x,y)? or What are the common properties of all such f(x,y)?"

Comment: @MarsOneRover: Yes, I sort of extended your question! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega=[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]$ and $u=\sin x \sin y$ .
We have, $u(0,y)=0$,$u(\pi,y)=0$, $u(x,0)=0$ and finally $u(x,\pi)=0$, so

$$u\big|_{\partial\Omega}=0$$

and hence

$$f(x,y)=c_1\cos x\sin y+c_2\sin x \cos y$$

Now you want to have the solution to

$$c_1u_x + c_2u_y=c_1\cos x\sin y+c_2\sin x \cos y$$
by characteristics.

Thus, $x_s=c_1$ so $x=c_1s+a$, similarly  $y=c_2s+b$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constant. Also, we can write

$$\eqalign{
  & {u_s} = {c_1}\cos x\sin y + {c_2}\sin x\cos y  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\, = {c_1}\cos ({c_1}s + a)\sin ({c_2}s + b) + {c_2}\sin ({c_1}s + a)\cos ({c_2}s + b) \cr} $$

so you got 
$$u = \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos \left(a-b+c_1 s-c_2 s\right)-\cos \left(a+b+\left(c_1+c_2\right) s\right)\right)=
\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos \left(x-y\right)-\cos \left(x+y\right)\right)=\sin x \sin y$$
as we could expected.

Comment: It is a good example. Voted Up! :) I think the OP is looking for **all** $f(x,y)$ with this property or at least it is more demanding to see it this way! :)

Comment: it is looks to me that he is asking about existence of such a function $f(x,y)$

Comment: Yes, you are right! :) The OP says: "Does there existe **a** function $f(x,y)$?" but it is more reasonable and interesting to search for **all**!  :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for every domain.... only $[0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$.

Comment: this is far from being the only domain. Just for example, what about $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $u=\sin \pi x\sin \pi y$?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Ok... that's equivalent.  Just rectangular domain is what I meant.

Comment: give me specific domain for which you cannot find such $f$(I'm a little busy, but I will try to respond)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the boundary is a closed smooth curve given by

$$\partial \Omega  = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right)|x = p(t),y = q(t),{t_1} \leqslant t \leqslant {t_2}} \right\}\tag{1}$$

According to the notion of the method of characteristic, we make the following change of variables:

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  x = x(s,t) \hfill \cr 
  y = y(s,t) \hfill \cr}  \right.\tag{2}$$

and make the following definitions

$$\eqalign{
  & z(s,t) = u(x(s,t),y(s,t))  \cr 
  & F(s,t) = f(x(s,t),y(s,t)) \cr}\tag{3}$$

Now we want our change of variables to come in handy, so we **require** that

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {{\partial x} \over {\partial s}} = {c_1},\,\,\,x({s_0},t) = p(t) \hfill \cr 
  {{\partial y} \over {\partial s}} = {c_2},\,\,\,y({s_0},t) = q(t) \hfill \cr}  \right.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left\{ \matrix{
  x(s,t) = {c_1}(s - {s_0}) + p(t) \hfill \cr 
  y(s,t) = {c_2}(s - {s_0}) + q(t) \hfill \cr}  \right.\,\tag{4}$$

where $s_0$ is some arbitrary real constant that you may choose whatever you want. Next, using **chain-rule**, $(3)$, $(4)$ and the PDE, we have

$${{\partial z} \over {\partial s}}\left( {s,t} \right) = F(s,t)\tag{5}$$

and hence

$$z(s,t) = \int\limits_{{s_0}}^s {F(\eta ,t)d\eta }\tag{6}$$

You can easily verify that $(6)$ satisfies both the PDE and BC. Now, we write $(6)$ in another form

$$u\left( {x(s,t),y(s,t)} \right) = \int\limits_{{s_0}}^s {f\left( {x(\eta ,t),y(\eta ,t)} \right)d\eta }\tag{7}$$

So, what I can say is that the $f$ you are looking for, must have the following property

$$\int\limits_{{s_0}}^s {f\left( {{c_1}(\eta  - {s_0}) + p(t),{c_2}(\eta  - {s_0}) + q(t)} \right)d\eta }  > 0\tag{8}$$

Or equivalently, if you choose $s_0=0$

$$\int\limits_0^s {f\left( {{c_1}\eta  + p(t),{c_2}\eta  + q(t)} \right)d\eta }  > 0\,\,\,\,\,\,for\,\,\,\,\forall \left( {s,t} \right):\left( {{c_1}s + p(t),{c_2}s + q(t)} \right) \in \Omega\tag{9}$$

---

**Some Suggestions**

1) I think you can get more out of $(9)$ but I didn't have time to go further. Try some tricks like change of variables in the integral. Maybe you got something!

2) We have found $z(s,t)=u(x(s,t),y(s,t))$. Try to find $u(x,y)$ from $(7)$. You should think on how to write the RHS in $(7)$ in terms of $x(s,t)$ and $y(s,t)$. Alternatively, you can think of finding $s=s(x,y)$ and $t=t(x,y)$ from $(4)$.

3) One more suggestion that I can make is to investigate this problem when

$$\eqalign{
  & {c_1} = {c_2} = 1  \cr 
  & \partial \Omega  = \left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right)|x = \cos t,y = \sin t,0 \le t \le 2\pi } \right\} \cr} $$

and then try to find your desired $f(x,y)$. Examining special cases is always helpful. :)

Comment: @MarsOneRover: Take a look at this. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: @Michael Medvinsky: Do you have any idea to improve this solution? :)

Comment: This integral condition is what I got of course, but it seems difficult to conclude anything from it.